# htaccess redirect to a new page but keeping "get" parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-parameters

I need to do a simple htaccess redirect to a new page and at the same time rename the "get" parameter. The original url is: `www.example.com/display_item.php?x=2735` and I want a redirect to:
`www.example.com/product.php?productcode=2735`.

Here is my latest attempt (of many) but this does not work and I get a 404 back:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /display_item.php?x=(.*)$  /product.php?productcode=$1
```

I think I am very close to solving this but I am pulling out my hair at the moment! I have looked on Stack Overflow for a solution, but nothing I have found works.

Comment: You did not read the documentation of the tools you try to use. The query string is _not_ part of the URL. Therefore your pattern will never match any request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the query string is not part of the URI. A such, you will need to use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to check the query string separately (using `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a condition).

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^display_item.php$ /product.php?id=%1 [L,R=302]
```

Change 302 to 301 to make the redirect permanent.

<sub>**Note:** In future, please review the relevant documentation (in order to get a better understanding of how everything works) before asking here on SO.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant thanks Mike - this worked!   I will now do some more research on this as I had completely gone off on the wrong tangent.... Thanks once again.